# Setting the result of a function to a variable in twig

Tags: php, twig

I have a function that generates an array containing menu items:

```
Item 1
  SubItem 1a
  SubItem 1b

Item2
  SubItem 2a
  ...
```

I have a twig extension that can return this as an array. I need to be able to set this array to a variable in twig, so that I can use it through out my template.

I have tried doing `{% set myArray = {{ myFunction('menuname') }} %}`

I also tried:

```
{% set myArray %}
  {{ myFunction('menuname') }}
{% endset %}
```

However, that did not work either. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!

Use `{% set myArray = myFunction('menuname') %}`

Comment: It's always the easiest, isn't it :X